# Power Shell in x86 process - Access 64 bit program files

Tags: redirect, powershell, program-files

I've used [SysNative](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384187%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) before to access the 64 bit system32 directory, but I don't seem to be able to find an equivalent for the Program Files directory. I feel like I'm missing something simple, but if I try to do something such as:

```
$command = "${Env:ProgramFiles}\Company\executable.exe"
```

Then `$command` ends up being C:\Program Files (x86)\Company\executable.exe.

Could anyone point me at the proper way of accessing the 64 bit program files (from 32 bit powershell)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Could be a lot shorter :)

```
$env:ProgramW6432
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out!

```
$programFiles = [System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("ProgramW6432")
```